# Copying single cell full of data, to a column?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, paste

I have a single cell full of data, that was put in that cell previously by creating an array and joining it. Now later on in the program, when asked, I want to take that cell full of the previous array data and paste it down a column on another sheet.

I have tried copying the cell and pasting using the range function, and also just using the first cell of the column i want to be used.

```
ws3.Activate
FinalRow2 = ws3.Range("E200").End(xlUp).Row
c = 21
a = 0

While a < VehCount

    VIN2 = VehArray(a)

    For b = 2 To FinalRow2
        ws3.Activate
            If Cells(b, 5) = VIN2 Then     'If VIN matches database
            Cells(b, 7).Copy               'Copy cell with array data
            ws4.Activate                   'Fault tab
            Cells(6, c).Paste              'Paste down column c     
            c = c + 9                      'increment c     
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate        'move down while scanning 
    Next b

    a = a + 1               'counter for VIN in VehArray

Wend
```

Cells(6, c).Paste is one option ive tried, I also tried Range(TOP Cell, BOTTOM Cell).PasteSpecial with wrong result.

What is the in the cell I want transferred is 840 bytes of data and they are spaced. I want each byte pasted in its own cell down column c in the other sheet.

The cell mentioned containing the byte array looks something like 17 5 5b 35 . .... and so on. 840 bytes in one cell. It is not in an array anymore because I am using a different sub.

Comment: "840 bytes of data and they are spaced" - might help to include a sample since it's not really clear what you mean by this.  Seems like you'd want to reverse the `Join()` using `Split()` and then assign the resulting array to the worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams of course, the cell I am talking about contains something like 34 6F 5A.... and on, 840 of those bytes. The problem is I am using a different function here so the array isn't recognized in this part of the code. I don't know how to pass an array through functions using vba.

Comment: Below a sample 80 byte HEX string

Comment: SampleStr = "BB B2 4A 3E F9 F4 88 68 80 67 A8 2D 39 6E 8F E1 61 7E 03 A7 71 3C 21 B2 1F B9 D1 04 B1 CB 73 2D 31 A9 C3 AB 86 DB 2A 38 51 76 E3 21 34 11 A5 E3 9D C3 81 64 3A 60 4A 39 DF A7 16 C2 FD 15 3D 84 81 92 01 49 23 E0 C6 A1 75 C0 BE 2F 39 80 35 EA "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
Dim arr

arr = Split(ws3.Cells(1, 1).Value, " ")

ws4.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
```

Note you should not rely on activating sheets in order to reference cells on the sheets - you can use the sheet directly to qualify your `Cells`/`Range` calls

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

[image]

```
Sub SampleStr840byte()
Dim myArray() As String
Dim SampleString As String
Dim iCt As Long

'Sample String 80 byte
'BB B2 4A 3E F9 F4 88 68 80 67 A8 2D 39 6E 8F E1 61 7E 03 A7 71 3C 21 B2 1F B9 D1 04 B1 CB 73 2D 31 A9 C3 AB 86 DB 2A 38 51 76 E3 21 34 11 A5 E3 9D C3 81 64 3A 60 4A 39 DF A7 16 C2 FD 15 3D 84 81 92 01 49 23 E0 C6 A1 75 C0 BE 2F 39 80 35 EA

'SampleString = "BB B2 4A 3E F9 F4 88 68 80 67 A8 2D 39 6E 8F E1 61 7E 03 A7 71 3C 21 B2 1F B9 D1 04 B1 CB 73 2D 31 A9 C3 AB 86 DB 2A 38 51 76 E3 21 34 11 A5 E3 9D C3 81 64 3A 60 4A 39 DF A7 16 C2 FD 15 3D 84 81 92 01 49 23 E0 C6 A1 75 C0 BE 2F 39 80 35 EA "



'I did save a 840 byte string in the cell A1!
SampleString = Range("A1").Value

myArray = Split(SampleString, " ")
MsgBox (sizeOfArray(myArray()))

For iCt = 1 To UBound(myArray)
Cells(iCt + 2, 3) = "'" & myArray(iCt - 1)
Next 'i

End Sub





'PROBLEM still existing? I haven't tried!
'
'Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(UBound(myArray), 3)) = myArray()
'This works only for a length of 1823 bytes
'(see http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;832136)
'Data May Be Truncated After 1,835 Characters When You Transfer Array Data to Cells in an Excel Worksheet



Function sizeOfArray(arr As Variant) As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim numDim As Integer
    Dim i

    numDim = NumberOfArrayDimensions(arr)
    str = "Array"

    For i = 1 To numDim
        str = str & "(" & LBound(arr, i) & " To " & UBound(arr, i)
        If Not i = numDim Then
            str = str & ", "
        Else
            str = str & ")"
        End If
    Next i

    sizeOfArray = str
End Function


Private Function NumberOfArrayDimensions(arr As Variant) As Integer
' By Chip Pearson
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm
Dim Ndx As Integer
Dim Res As Integer
On Error Resume Next
' Loop, increasing the dimension index Ndx, until an error occurs.
' An error will occur when Ndx exceeds the number of dimension
' in the array. Return Ndx - 1.
    Do
        Ndx = Ndx + 1
        Res = UBound(arr, Ndx)
    Loop Until Err.Number <> 0
NumberOfArrayDimensions = Ndx - 1
End Function

Sub arrSizeTester()
    Dim arr(1 To 2, 3 To 22, 2 To 9, 12 To 18) As Variant
    Debug.Print sizeOfArray(arr())
End Sub
```

Comment: See comment from Tim Williams above, Im sure this would work in many instances but not in mine, thank you for the answer though!